# using UIDatePicker on static cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uistoryboard

I want to display the date picked from UIDatePicker on the **static cell**.

[image: screen]

The problem code is below. I want to change `self.label.text` by changing the date with UIDatePicker, but it doesn't change.

```
- (IBAction)inputDate:(id)sender {
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.datePicker.date];
}
```

- Method `inputDate:` is wired to UIDatePicker.
- Property `datePicker` is also wired to UIDatePicker.

Is there any specific way to change static cells? Thanks for your kindness.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one row code solved the Problem. Stunner's advice is very helpful for this final answer.

```
- (IBAction)inputDate:(id)sender {
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.datePicker.date];
    [self.tableView reloadData]; // <- add this row !
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Something worth noting... if you have multiple rows/sections in a table view and need to update only one cell, it would be inefficient to call `[tableView reloadData]` as that would reload all sections/rows of your table view resulting in wasted computation. Instead use the method I suggested in my answer or another sister method (that reloads by cell rather than section).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you store the cell that you want to change as an ivar in your table view:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //...
    // configure your birth date cell
    self.birthDateCell = cell;
    //...
}
```

Then your method would look something like:

```
- (IBAction)inputDate:(id)sender {
    self.birthDateCell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sender.date];
}
```

And that should do it. Additionally, make sure you are calling the inputDate function with the appropriate event action for the date picker.

**EDIT:** Additionally, you may need to reload your cell to present the data like so:

```
- (IBAction)inputDate:(id)sender {
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sender.date];
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] 
                      withRowAnimation:NO];
}
```

Comment: `self.label` is wired to cell above. I think the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is not necessary for **static cells**, and it is trouble making because existing cell is overloaded by new cell.

Comment: As far as I know (I don't have experience with storyboards) you still need to have the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for that cell but can return a xib-loaded cell for that cell. I edited my answer in response to your edited question.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information about **reload** table. With storyboard, we don't have to write `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method. I think this is most important improvement of iOS SDK by the storyboard. The tableViewController become much clear.